# Compare two files, print lines with common first and second Column and create new table

Tags: bash

I am working with the Bash shell.

I have two text files.

First lines of the first one:

```
Datum           Diffuse Radiation   Global Radidation   Direkte_Strahlung   Minute
26.02.13 12:23  240,5   783,5   543 23
26.02.13 12:24  243,8   752 508,2   24
26.02.13 12:25  248,9   660 411,1   25
26.02.13 12:26  262,2   653,7   391,5   26
26.02.13 12:27  281,3   612,4   331,1   27
26.02.13 12:28  315,1   864,8   549,7   28
```

First lines of the second file:

```
Date    Time (past local midnight)  Solar Zenith Angle (deg)    Cos_Zenitwinkel Luftmasse
26.02.13    0:00:00 161,7649831 -0,949780987    -1,052874308
26.02.13    0:06:00 161,7258048 -0,949566797    -1,053111801
26.02.13    0:12:00 161,5769749 -0,948749087    -1,054019459
26.02.13    0:18:00 161,3211217 -0,947328405    -1,055600143
26.02.13    0:24:00 160,9625742 -0,945305712    -1,057858836
```

Both text files are separated with tabs. In the first file is just a space between the date and hour - my question is: I want to get those lines from each file as an output with the common dates & hours.

My idea is to compare the files line by line with a command, get a txt.file as an output with all the dates&hours they have in common -> `common_date.file`.

Then I compare the `common_date.file` with the first file and get a new file with only the date & hours of the `common_date.file` (but the whole line is printed!). Then I do the same thing with the second file.

I know there is the command `-diff` for getting the difference of two files.

I already tried `grep -F -x -f` but it didn't work either. I think it should work with grep!

Maybe I explain my wish like this:

I want to get two new files with the date & hours they have in common. So that the length of the two files is equal and I can make a plot with a time axis.

Comment: Both files have different time format. Suggest you provide better sample data with your expected data.

Comment: the problem is, when I use sed -e 's= =\t=g' on the first file, it doesn't get the \t as a tab - so I am not able to change it. I tried some other tab-characters, but it didn't work out.

Comment: I will upload the data and post the link, ok?

Comment: first file: https://ufile.io/17cd9 and second file: https://ufile.io/d30f8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can grep substrings for file1 in file2 and vice versa. You will find the substrings with

```
cut -d $'\t' -f1-2 file2 |sed 's/\t/ /g'
cut -d $'\t' -f1   file1 |sed 's/ /\t/g'
```

You can store the output of the `cut-sed` in a temp file and use `grep -f` for grepping with the temp file.
You can avoid the temp file with process substitution:

```
grep -f <(cut -d $'\t' -f1-2 file2 |sed 's/\t/ /g') file1 >file1.out
grep -f <(cut -d $'\t' -f1   file1 |sed 's/ /\t/g') file2 >file2.out
```